# Android Oauth Exception with SMTP Transport connect,with android version 2.3

Tags: android, oauth, gmail, oauth-2.0

I am getting following error when I try to run my android project after adding new AUTH XOAUTH2 command.I am using android device with os version 2.3 but same code is working fine on android 4.0

```
    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail,String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception 
{

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
    session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(debug);


    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
    // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
    final String emptyPassword = null;
    transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

    byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail,oauthToken).getBytes();
    response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

    transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response),235);

    return transport;
}
```

Please check the logs

```
03-21 10:05:08.679: W/System.err(987): javax.mail.MessagingException: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
03-21 10:05:08.679: W/System.err(987):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1481)
03-21 10:05:08.679: W/System.err(987):  at com.swapmeen.test.GMailOauthSender.connectToSmtp(GMailOauthSender.java:48)
03-21 10:05:08.679: W/System.err(987):  at com.swapmeen.test.GMailOauthSender.sendMail(GMailOauthSender.java:57)
03-21 10:05:08.679: W/System.err(987):  at com.swapmeen.test.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:64)
```

Comment: I m also getting exception ... through scanning found error at issueCommand() method of transport. Anyone suggest what command and expect should be there for google accounts

Comment: Hi, did either of you ever get this working?

Answer (score 5):

The error you are receiving

```
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
```

decodes to the following using a Base64 Decoder

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

What this ends up meaning (as cryptic as the message is) is that the authentication token that you are using has expired. You need to invalidate it and then get a new one (simply request the token again).

You invalidate the token like this:

```
mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", mAuthenticationToken);
```

I hope that this is helpful :)

Comment: I did what you posted but and my app gets a new token, however I still receive this message...

Comment: Small update, it should be "com.google" not "con.google"