# Sending email without user interaction in android using OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, smtp

I am getting this error while trying to connect to smtp

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
```

Here is my code

```
public class GMailOauthSender
{
    private Session session;

    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail, String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;
        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

        byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        return transport;
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user, String oauthToken, String recipients) {
        try {
            SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com",587,user,oauthToken,true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));   
            message.setSubject(subject);   
            message.setDataHandler(handler);   

            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
            else  
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   

            smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have got this code from some where in stack overflow.
any help??

Comment: Try this, it may help you. [Send mail using smtp](http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/search/label/Gmail%20integration%20in%20Android) Let me know even if you have any problem.

Comment: hi Hashmukh thanks for giving reply. this is fine but i want to send email from the account where user has already setup in mobile. in this case how can i get password here..?

Comment: it mean Google play Ac, Password while setting AC in Mobile ?

Comment: yes exactly . do you have any idea about in that way.

Comment: NO Sorry dear, even let try to find out for you some another way.

Comment: Check the value of oathtoken. It's probably null and that's the reason that google returns that error. If you use base64 decoder the error is: {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Oauth Exception with SMTP Transport connect,with android version 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539654/android-oauth-exception-with-smtp-transport-connect-with-android-version-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving

```
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
```

decodes to the following using a Base64 Decoder

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

What this ends up meaning (as cryptic as the message is) is that the authentication token that you are using has expired. You need to invalidate it and then get a new one (simply request the token again).

You invalidate the token like this:

```
mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("con.google", mAuthenticationToken);
```

I hope that this is helpful :)